# i want to know the columns names which i had issued primary key in sql ? what is the syntax?

Tags: sql

want to know the columns names which i had issued primary key in sql ? what is the syntax ?

Comment: What database system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME ,column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.key_column_usage
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('*your_schema_name*');
```

Hope This Will help You.

Answer (score -1):

```
USE databasename; 

GO
 SELECT i.name AS IndexName, OBJECT_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName, 
           COL_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID,ic.column_id) AS ColumnName
    FROM sys.indexes AS i
    INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic
    ON i.OBJECT_ID = ic.OBJECT_ID
    AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
    WHERE i.is_primary_key = 1
```

Comment: `Error Code: 1146. Table 'sys.indexes' doesn't exist` … 

Comment: Ok maybe you use another database, but than I get: `ERROR:  relation "sys.indexes" does not exist
LINE 5: FROM sys.indexes AS i
             ^
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 134`

Comment: @Luuk  Are you using sql? I can un above query in sql sever.

Comment: somegeek: Your solution only works on 'Microsoft SQL Server', the solution from @Shaifat works on more servers (and als on MSSQL-server)